# Offline (!) similarity/plagiarism detection tool

Tags: plagiarism

Can anyone please suggest an offline similarity check software which could work with a *custom* database of PDF or text files? Motivation: I have lots of previous reports from students (these are not available online and therefore online plagiarism checkers will not detect a thing) and I need to use them as a database against which to check the reports that are submitted by the current students. Of course, I could check every report against each of the previous ones using some diff tool, but that would be hugely inefficient and a lot of pain on top of that.

Thanks.

nvx

Comment: What about some vba macro to apply the diff tool then?

Comment: @SolarMike: O(n^2)

Comment: @SolarMike: Thanks. I guess this might work, but then again -- how do I force the diff tool to output some meaningful score? All such utilities I know of are for visual comparison (which I want to have available too as a second step). Still, if you know of anything of this sort, please let me know, because hacking together a Python or other script would be quite easy (even though the comparisons would be rather slow for larger numbers of reports in the database).